# Support for port number in hostname in Certificate Pinner

Tags: java, android, okhttp

```
private static final String Sha256="sha256/hxvqB+muy3jP5UZQ4CrRIr7oK0DourlxQCzr7UpTTVY=" ;

final static CertificatePinner certificate = new 
CertificatePinner.Builder().add("172.18.10.10:8090",Sha256).build();
```

When i run the above code , the exception says

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid pattern: 172.18.10.10:8090`

But i never get the same error , when i put the hostname without any port number i.e just 172.18.10.10

The CertificatePinner is not accepting hostnames with portnumber i guess , due to the validity checking

Is there any work around available to add port number along with hostname in CertificatePinner

Answer (score 1):

There is no such mechanism.

Note that pinning a host or host+port combination will not allow you to connect to a host you can't otherwise connect to. Certificate pinning only reduces connectivity; it never increases it.

Comment: But I thought CertifcatePinning was used to add support for self signed certificates with the sha checksums of the certificates.. So it facilitates the connectivity which was previously not available right?

Comment: Nope. If you're using self-signed certificates you need to configure the trust manager to know about them